# Best way to Update a List Concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-dynamodb, distributed-system

I have a multi-threaded application. The application takes an input which has a field "classifier" which is a string and few other helper fields .The input is processed and a List of Unique Strings are generated. This List of Strings need to updated with respect to field Classifier.

My Approach was to use a dynamo Db where primary key is the classifier and maintain a Set. The Set is updated for each List of Strings that are generated. I feel this adds much overhead as the TPS is around 2000 distributed among the instances and input with same classifier field can be repeated for upto 30,000 times. Is there any better approach to store all the List of Strings that are generated against classifier field.

Comment: Could you give an example of how the `List of Strings` look like?

Comment: It looks something like this classifier=something|field1=abc|field2=UUID|field3=def

Answer (score 0):

You can store hash of list along with storing actual list. Hence classifier_table should have 3 columns:

classifier_id | list of string | HASH_OF_LIST

For each incoming request process like following:

```
h1 <- Create a hash(list of strings)

h2 <- select HASH_OF_LIST from classifier_table where classifier_id == <classifier_id>

if h1 != h2:
  insert into classifier_table (list of strings, h2) for classifier_id == <classifier_id>
```